# Trying to add an attachment to an Estimate via PHP (works but, doesn't.)

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

This is my second day messing with the PHP SDK, I've encountered a road block with uploading an attachment to an Estimate with my code. I wanted a PHP form where one can upload a file and shoot it into the QBO company; my first step was to first try and set a static variable to see if it works, my code look slike this:

```
$Estimate = $dataService->query("SELECT * FROM Estimate WHERE DocNumber in ('{$ID}')"); 

// Create a new IPPAttachable

$up = "http://www.somedomain.com/test.pdf";

$sendMimeType = "application/pdf";

$randId = rand();

$entityRef = new IPPReferenceType($Estimate->Id);

$attachableRef = new IPPAttachableRef($entityRef);

$objAttachable = new IPPAttachable();

$objAttachable->FileName = $randId."TEST02.pdf";

//$objAttachable->AttachableRef = $Estimate->DocNumber;

$objAttachable->AttachableRef = $attachableRef;

$objAttachable->Note = "Test";

$objAttachable->ContentType = $sendMimeType;



$resultObj = $dataService->Upload($up,

$objAttachable->FileName,

$sendMimeType,

$objAttachable);
```

This code fires, adds an attachment to the proper estimate but the attachment is less than 1k and is unreadable. Almost as if it never fetched the document to attach, it simply made some kind of a "generic" success.

Can anyone assist with updating the above code? I'm sure its right in front of me, but I keep missing.

Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out, I had to pass a file and encode in Base64, specify the Base64 contents and it finally went through. Thanks if anyone was researching.